# How to rename filenames considering their IDs

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I'm a begginer with R programming. I have downloaded many pictures which have their ID as name. For example, pictures "senador588", "senador3", "senador16" and so on. Each picture shows one senator of Brazil. I need the name instead of the ID.

I also have a dataframe which displays only the ID (id_senador) and the name (name_lower).

## This first part of the code downloads all the pictures:

```
library(data.table)
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(purrr)
# all the senators of Brazil
url <- "https://www25.senado.leg.br/web/senadores/em-exercicio/-/e/por-nome"


# get all url on the webpage
url2 <- getURL(url)
parsed <- htmlParse(url2)
links <- xpathSApply(parsed,path = "//a",xmlGetAttr,"href")

links <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, links) 

colnames(links)[1] <- "links" 


# filtering to get the urls of the senators
links_senador <- links %>%
  filter(links %like% "/senadores/senador/")

links_senador <- data.frame(links_senador)

# creating a new directory for the pics
setwd("~/Downloads/")
dir.create("senadores-new")
setwd("~/Downloads/senadores-new")
  
# running a loop to download all pictures
i <- 1
while(1 <= 81){
  tryCatch({
# defining the row of each senator
  foto_webpage <- data.frame(links_senador$links[i])
# renaming the column's name
  colnames(foto_webpage) <- "links" 
# getting all images of html page
# filtering the photo which we want
  html <- as.character(foto_webpage$links) %>%
    httr::GET() %>%
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_nodes("img") %>%
    map(xml_attrs) %>%
    map_df(~as.list(.)) %>%
    filter(src %like% "senadores/img/fotos-oficiais/") %>%
    as.data.frame(html)
# downloading the photo
    foto_senador <- html$src
    download.file(foto_senador, basename(foto_senador), mode = "wb", header = TRUE)
    Sys.sleep(3)
  }, error = function(e) return(NULL)
  )
  i <- i + 1
}
```

## This second part creates a dataframe with the ID and name of each senator:

```
url <- "https://www25.senado.leg.br/web/senadores/em-exercicio/-/e/por-nome"

file <- read_html(url)
tables <- html_nodes(file, "table")
table1 <- html_table(tables[1], fill = TRUE, header = T)


table1_df <- as.data.frame(table1)[1]

table1_df_sem_acentuacao <- as.data.frame(iconv(table1_df$Nome, from = "UTF-8", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT"))
colnames(table1_df_sem_acentuacao) <- "senador_lower"

table1_df_lower <- as.data.frame(tolower(table1_df_sem_acentuacao$senador_lower))
colnames(table1_df_lower) <- "senador_lower"

table_name_final <- as.data.frame(gsub(" ", "-", table1_df_lower$senador_lower))

id_split <- as.data.frame(gsub("https://www25.senado.leg.br/web/senadores/senador/-/perfil/", "senador", links_senador$links))

table_dfs_final <- cbind(table_name_final, id_split)
colnames(table_dfs_final)[1] <- "name_lower"
colnames(table_dfs_final)[2] <- "id_senador"
```

## For the loop to replace the ID for the name, I tried this:

```
for (p in photos) {
  id <- basename(p)
  id <- gsub(".jpg$", "", id)
  name <- table_dfs_final$name_lower[match(id,         basename(table_dfs_final$id_senador))]
  fname <- paste0(table_dfs_final$id_senador, ".jpg")
  file.rename(p, fname)
  
  #optional
  cat("renaming", basename(p), "to", name, "\n")
}
```

Comment: so you just want to rename the file ?  what is the question?

Comment: yes, I want to rename the files. I need to change from ID to name_lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more "R way" you can use one of the functions from apply family. create your function that changes names and than just apply it on ids and names columns you created.

```
changeName<- function(old_name, new_name){

  file.rename(paste0(old_name,'.jpg'), paste0(new_name,'.jpg'))
}


mapply(changeName, table_dfs_final$id_senador,table_dfs_final$name_lower)
```

Comment: It didn't work and returned "FALSE FALSE FALSE". I have 81 IDs/name, so I can't write each inside as it appers on "id_senador = c(1,2,3)" and "name_lower = c('cuevas', 'asare', 'lumb)"

Comment: @ana sorry for confusion. you can remove that part. it was just to create a sample of names in my env and than some random names that were replacing the ids. so in my case 1,2,3 are ids and strings are names of senators. I edited my answer. you can run your code and instead of looping ceate changeName function and mapply then.

Comment: It returned in the console this: " [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[21] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[41] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[81] FALSE". And the names of the files didn't change :(

Comment: @ana of course they didn't because I'm stupid and your pictures format is jpg not png. try now...

Comment: It still doesn't change the name of the file... :( Now it returns "[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[35] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[52] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[69] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE"

Comment: @ana does it mean that first one was changed?

Comment: @ana can you show me head of table_dfs_final? and exact names of few files

Comment: here is the head of table_df_final [http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=eiqh76&s=9] and also here:               name_lower  id_senador
1           acir-gurgacz senador4981
2            aecio-neves  senador391
3 aloysio-nunes-ferreira  senador846
4            alvaro-dias  senador945
5             ana-amelia senador4988
6         angela-portela senador4697

Comment: do you have files in your working env? because it looks like everything is fine except files are not where R expects them. also if there are special characters in file names there will be an issue.

Comment: crazy stuff. happy to help.